# What does sendsignal.exe do?

Tags: java, logging, dump

I hear that [sendsignal.exe](http://www.latenighthacking.com/projects/2003/sendsignal/) is used to write logs of java applications to a file. Would you please give more information about what it does and how it does it? In plain english please, I'm not an expert programmer.

And what is "CTRL+break"? I don't see a "break" button on my keyboard.

Comment: `CTRL + C` to [break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The `break` key is usually the unshifted version of the `pause` key, and is in the area of the keyboard near the `print screen` and `scroll lock` keys. @Pau, `Ctrl+C` is different than `Ctrl+Break`; they're different key codes and do different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Singals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) are a Unix concept, they are some kind of limited interprocess communication.

To create a thread dump you send the signal SIGQUIT to a process, the signal is trapped and the thread dump will be written. You could also send other signals e.g. to terminate a process.

To send a signal on unix you would use the kill command:

```
kill -3 <pid>
```

the java way would be:

```
jstack <pid>
```

your sendsignal.exe will probably do the same.